# Put the "journaltitle" in article between brackets using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex in a document with the `verbose-trad1` style. The problem is that I need to put the Journal Title in the bibliography between brackets. 
I've just found a way to avoid the Journal Title to be in italics :
`\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}`
But no way to adapt in to put the title between brackets....

I hope my request is clear enough !

Thanks

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}`?

Comment: WOW! that was fast and works great !!!! Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

in your preamble.

Note in particular that *internally* for `biblatex` there is no field `journal`, there is only `journaltitle`. In the `.bib` file you may use either `journal` or `journaltitle`, but both get resolved to `journaltitle` by Biber (or BibTeX).

Comment: you saved my life...I was doing the craziest things with my bib-file to redeclare and whatever. I needed it non-italic, but it's the same.
I forgot the `*title` part I just wrote `\DeclareFieldFormat{journal}{\textsf{#1}}` to try to make the article journal-field not italic.
Solution: `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textsf{#1}}`