# Styling the bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Example bibliography displays this way right now:

> [1] John Doe et al. Book Title. Publisher, 2023.

I want it to display that way:

> [1] Doe J., Smith A., Parker P., Edwards J. Book Title. Publisher, 2023.

I have absolutely no idea how to do it, no matter what I try it either doesn't compile or just does nothing. I'm considering abandoning automatic bibliography packages and simply do it manually. It will take a lot of time, but at least it will work, unlike `biblatex`.

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Bibliography management}
\author{Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\medskip

\section{First Section}
Cite \cite{author00}.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibliography file:

```
@book{author00,
    title = {Book Title},
    author = {John Doe and Adam Smith and Peter Parker and John Edwards},
    year = {2023},
    publisher = {Publisher},
}
```

Comment: @JamesT 3 errors 2 warnings, I won't be able to show them fully here. `Package biblatex Error: Style 'author-year' not found.` `Package biblatex Error: Style 'author-year' not found.` `Package biblatex Error: Command '\cite' undefined.` `Empty bibliography on input line 24` `The file 'output.bcf' does not contain any citations!`

Comment: Yes my apologies, I spelt the style file wrong, ignore that comment! Working on an answer now

Comment: How do you want the in-text citation to look? Like this `(1)` or `Doe et al 2023`? Could you edit that into your question please, probably easy to use a default class and modify it

Comment: @JamesT default [ID_of_book] would be the best. So far style `apa` is the closest to what I want (still not perfect though) but it breaks citation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you only want to change the presentation of the author names. Almost all of the changes you need can be found in the introduction to `biblatex` customisation in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

Increase `maxbibnames` to a high value to show all names, set `giveninits` to `true` to show only the given name initials.

Then you just need to change the name format from the `default` `given-family` to `family-given`.

If you don't like to see an "and" before the last author and prefer the comma instead, redefine `finalnamedelim`. (See e.g. [Deleting the "and" inside the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446997/35864.))

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  maxbibnames=999,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author00,
  title     = {Book Title},
  author    = {John Doe and Adam Smith and Peter Parker and John Edwards},
  year      = {2023},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
Cite \autocite{author00}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] Doe, J., Smith, A., Parker, P., Edwards, J. Book Title. Publisher, 2023.]

Comment: May I ask one more thing? How to style title and article fields? It will often default to cursive, but what if I want quotation marks, or just title without any styling?

Comment: Not article but journal fields, sorry for error.

Comment: @walter54 See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 for the title field. Use `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}` or `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}` for the journal name. Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178713/35864.